# PDO: данные в таблицу не пишутся

Tags: php_pdo, postgresql

Пробую писать данные в PostgreSQL при помощи PDO. Но реакции на мои действия - ноль. Вот собственно проблемный блок:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table(id_keypreset, key, order) VALUES(:preset, :key, :order);";
$sth   = $dbh->prepare($query);
for ($x=0; $x<count($presetmeta); $x++) {
  $sth->execute(array(
    ':preset' => $id_item,
    ':key'    => $presetmeta[$x],
    ':order'  => $x
  ));
}
```

Глаз на явные ошибки пока не наметан, поэтому буду рад любым наводкам на причины, почему это не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что одно из полей таблицы (order) совпадало с SQL-командой. Лечится кавычками:

```
'INSERT INTO keypresetsmeta(id_keypreset, key, "order") 
      VALUES(:id_keypreset, :key, :order);'
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вот так:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO table(id_keypreset, key, order) VALUES(:preset, :key, :order);";
$sth   = $dbh->prepare($query);
for ($x=0; $x<count($presetmeta); $x++) {
  $sth->execute(array(
    'preset' => $id_item,
    'key'    => $presetmeta[$x],
    'order'  => $x
  ));
}
```

то есть в ключах массива символ ":" не указывается

Comment: Спасибо. Буду знать, что двоеточие здесь вариативное. Когда оно есть, очевиднее, к чему массив относится. 

Но проблема была в другом - одно из полей таблицы совпадает с SQL-командой. Лечится кавычками:

    'INSERT INTO keypresetsmeta(id_keypreset, key, "order") 
    VALUES(:id_keypreset, :key, :order);';